# Unix AIX version 7.1 and 7.2

Tags: unix, aix

I am working on Unix AIX, after searching I found log format for AIX v6.1 but didn't find logs for V7.1 and V7.2 Please let me know the link for log reference guide or syslog log messages because I need to understand the log fields.

Comment: So you cannot find the syslog files, or don't understand their content? Perhaps you want to process the files programatically?

Comment: I want a guide which clearly explains the syslog for all the events.For ex:PROC_Kill root OK Wed Jan 31 13:52:32 2007 bash pid:
405524, sig: 1. I didn't find logs for backup and restore, tcpip, port changed, account enable and disable. if I get complete guide which explains the classes with examples , it will be helpful

Comment: Need to know that syslog field remains same for V6.1 and V7.1.

Comment: Need to know that syslog field remains same for V6.1 and V7.1. I have a log fields for V6.1 like: event, login, status, date and command i.e event id PROC_Kill, login is root, status is ok, date is wed jan 31 , command is bash pid:405524.so now iam looking for V7.1

Comment: This is unreadable due to the lack of formatting. Please edit the original post (add these lines into the post, preceded with four spaces).

Comment: I have AIX V6.1 logs i.e PROC_Kill root OK Wed Jan 31 13:52:32 2007 bashpid:405524 .                                                                                               Now i am in need of V7.1 logs. so please help me with configuration guide that has commands , classes and examples.